# JFrame inside JApplet

Tags: java, jframe, japplet

I have program which based on JFrame. now I want to run it on web page. it seems I must use JApplet . what should I do ? can I have JApplet window and many JFrame windows and it can run on the web?

```
package Interface;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;    
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;    
import Interface.Menu.block;    

public class Menu extends JApplet {
    static int rows=8;
    static int cols=8;
    MenuLabel menulabel ;
     public enum block
        {Ground,Wall,Ice,Trap,Box;
        }
     public static Start start; 

    @Override

    public void init() {
//      super("Menu");    
//      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBounds(300, 100, 600,600);
        menulabel= new MenuLabel(8,8);
        add(menulabel);
        Main.menu=this;
        JMenuBar load=new JMenuBar();
        load.add(new Loadbutton());
        new JFrame().setVisible(true);
        add(load);

        Startbutton Start = new Startbutton(this);
        Loadbutton Load =new Loadbutton();
        Editbutton Edit = new Editbutton();
        add(Start);
        add(Load);
        add(Edit);

        paint(this.getGraphics());
    }    
};
 class MenuLabel extends JLabel implements Cloneable
{  
     int rows,cols;
    public  MenuMap [][] menumap;
    MenuLabel(int rows,int cols)
    {
        Menu.rows=rows;
        Menu.cols=cols;
        this.rows=rows;
        this.cols=cols;
        setBounds(140,100,580,580);
        menumap=new MenuMap[rows][cols];
        add(new JButton("sds"));
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            {
                menumap[i][j]=new MenuMap(j*50,i*50,block.Ground);
                menumap[i][j].setBounds(j*50, i*50, 50, 50);
                add(menumap[i][j]);
            }
    }
    void changeCell(int x ,int y,Menu.block b)
    {
        removeAll();            
        menumap[x][y]=new MenuMap(menumap[x][y].getX(), menumap[x][y].getY(),b);
        for(int i=0;i<Menu.rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<Menu.cols;j++)
                add(menumap[i][j]);
    }
    public MenuLabel(MenuLabel another)
    {
        this.cols=another.cols;
        this.rows=another.rows;
        setBounds(140,100,580,580);
        menumap=new MenuMap[rows][cols];
        add(new JButton("sds"));
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            {
                menumap[i][j]=new MenuMap(j*50,i*50,
                Menu.block.valueOf(another.menumap[i][j].getText()));
                menumap[i][j].setBounds(j*50, i*50, 50, 50);
                add(menumap[i][j]);
            }
    }
    MenuMap getCell(int i, int j)
    {
        return menumap[i][j];
    }
    public int getRows(){return this.rows;}
    public int getCols(){return this.cols;}    
}
```

Comment: BTW `setLayout(null);`  Don't do that.  Use layouts.  `setBounds(300, 100, 600,600);` Won't work for an embedded applet.

Answer (score 2):

> I have program which based on JFrame.

Launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @mKorbel:  When you get time to try it, download some of the small examples I have on the [JWS API Examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html) page.  Each has a build file to get it up & running easily.  They are mostly quite trivial, but hopefully instructive. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without diving to your code, the answer is yes, you can. 
You can create JFrame, set its size (and position) then make it visible. Your frame will appear separately from browser's window. The only question is why? Think about user: it is very inconvenient when web application creates number of pop-up windows.

Comment: i think it is better to use jpanel instead of jframe and change their visibility or add/remove them. what do you think.